# What is wrong with this variable assignment for this regex

Tags: regex, bash, sh

Simple regex to check the conditions if the entered string is matched as an IP address.  If the regex compared directly to the argument, it was working fine but not if I used a variable assignment for the regex.

I've tested with some different syntax but still not working unless if I am using the regex directly.

```
#!/bin/bash

#provide one word/sentence as an argument to the script. If in that sentence will be ip address,
#find out, if that ip address is reachable or not.

#argument check

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Provide exactly one argument e.g. $0 argument"
   exit 1
fi

var1=$1
#ip address regex 127.0.0.1
regexp="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"


#regex check
#if ! [[ $var1 =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} ]]; then
if ! [[ $var1 =~ $regexp ]]; then
   echo "No IP address provided"
   exit 2
fi

IP=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}

#find if ip address is reachable or not
ping -c4 $IP
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   status="Alive"
else
   status="Dead"
fi

echo "IP found: $IP ($status)"
```

with:

```
 if ! [[ $var1 =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} ]]; then
```

It's working fine but not with:

```
 regexp="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
```

```
 if ! [[ $var1 =~ $regexp ]]; then
```

I have researched many articles but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1,3}` != `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}`

Comment: Note that the return code is `2`, which indicates that the regex is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
#                              ^
```

should be

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
#                              ^
```

Comment: Gosh, thanks for pointing that out, somehow I missed that part after numerous times reading it through. Thanks a lot, sorry for this newbie mistake